# How to prove $(\textit{P}_{1} \wedge \textit{P}_{2}) \Rightarrow \textit{Q}$

Tags: proof-writing, propositional-calculus

I wish to prove a proposition of the form $(\textit{P}_{1} \wedge \textit{P}_{2}) \Rightarrow \textit{Q}$.

In our lecture, we have been taught to assume $\textit{P}_{1}$ and $\textit{P}_{2}$ and then show that $\textit{Q}$ holds. However, I came across an exercise problem but it somehow requires us to divide the proof into cases. How am I supposed to do so?

Thanks in advance and regards.

Comment: $\land$ is conjunction. Assume $P_1 \land P_2$, from which both $P_1$ and $P_2$ follow. Now you have to derive $Q$.

Comment: Case 1: $P_1⇒Q.\quad$ Case 2: $P_2⇒Q.\quad$ Cases 1 and 2 together (i.e., both sentences being true) implies $(P_1∧P_2)⇒Q.$  Is this what you mean by cases?

Comment: @ryang yes that is what I mean by dividing into cases. I previously thought that a proof outline, similar to that which you provided is for proving $(\textit{P}_{1} \vee \textit{P}_{2}) \Rightarrow \textit{Q}$ only.

Comment: @rlddaguro Great! Though technically, we aren’t “dividing into cases”, as our two cases are neither mutually exclusive nor exhaustive.